# Does ASP.NET multithreading impact Structuremap singleton class?

Tags: c#, thread-safety, singleton, structuremap

In my ASP.NET MVC project I have a class which is instantiated via Structuremap and is configured as a singleton.

Given that ASP.NET is inherently multithreaded and the Singleton pattern is not threadsafe by default, will it cause any issues?

I faced an issue where multiple instances were being returned for a class configured as Singleton. Could this problem be because of the instances being requested from different threads.

EDIT : A more detailed description is given on this question.[Structuremap in Singleton returning multiple instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16732401/structuremap-in-singleton-returning-multiple-instances?noredirect=1#comment24116591_16732401)

EDIT2 : Here is a description of what my class does

```
class DerviedClass: BaseInterface
{
   ISession session

   DerivedClass()
   {
      session = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<ISession>();
   }

   public bool DoWork
   {
       return session.QueryOver<MyTable>().RowCount() > 0;
   }
}
```

Comment: It is not a singleton class. It is a regular class configured in StructureMap as Singleton. More data on my setup - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16732401/structuremap-in-singleton-returning-multiple-instances?noredirect=1#comment24116591_16732401

Comment: Could you, please, provide some details what is that 'singleton' doing for you? If there are only read methods (get localized strings, get users list, return MetaData, return set of ValidationRules - that's my approach) singleton is not an issue. If it would do any write operations, the "perthread instance" could be the right choice. Please, extend the question with the purpose, if possible.

Comment: StructureMap is thread-safe, but if you return a single instance of some class in a multi-threaded application, that class itself must be thread-safe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking into account your extended version, the example of the `DerviedClass`: I would say, that this is a very risky, and could cause lot of issues.

My concerns:

1) ASP.`NET` + `NHibernate` == `ISession` per *Request*. Other words, when application starts *(triggered by first request most likely, which could be more often if automated restarts ar in place)*, the Singleton is created and provided with an instance of the `ISession` per *Current Request* i.e *First Request*.

Well at least, the `ISession` should be recieved via `Factory` whenever needed, to be sure, that it is *Current Request* related.

2) In case, that the NHibernate `ISession` created in constructor, is intended to be indpendent on the *Current Request*, it could mean:

- it is long running, opened and not closed among more requests - possible lock issues. Or
- there is needed some open/close ISession management, not based on the current request

The point is, that I do not see the benefit of the Singleton pattern here. We do not need and do not provide common, request indpendent stuff.

We do return data dependent to the request (and its session scope). So, what I would suggest to use:

```
.HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped()
```

The overhead with creating instance per request is nothing in comparison with the benefit of logical life-cycle usage.

But, yes, this is just my suggestion... Because I see many potential issues (locking, un-intended changes ala dirty object in the session which could be commited etc.)

Comment: Hi Radim, thanks for your thoughts. What would be the ideal way of implementing a service which returns static data which doesnt change throughout the lifecycle of the application. since this data doesnt change, I was hoping not to have to fire multiple queries to the DB. The easiest way to achieve this would be to use static, but I don't want to lose out on testability, Hence I went for the singleton,

Answer (score 1):

You must make the singleton thread-safe by making sure that every property set block uses a lock, like so:

```
public int Counter
{
    get { return _counter; }

    set
    {
        lock(_counterLock)
        {
            _counter = value;
        }
    }
}

private int _counter = 0;

private object _counterLock = new Object();
```

Comment: My class is not singleton. It is made singleton by ObjectFactory's configuration. I have edited the question to include more details (at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16732401/structuremap-in-singleton-returning-multiple-instances?noredirect=1#comment24116591_16732401)

Comment: If it is managed as a singleton, then de facto it is a singleton, isn't it? There is one living instance that is shared by all, and so it must be made thread-safe using the method above.

Comment: But the class itself doesnt have a private constructor. It is structureMap which caches the instance on first  request. I am not sure if this also requires threadsafe code. Will give it a try

Comment: It does. As there is only one instance no matter how you look at it, all threads pass through that single instance, and your code must be thread-safe.